# Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, javascript-controller, geolocation

I want to show the geoposition on a leaflet map lightning component. I enter an Id and get geolocation data accordingly. When I first enter an Id everything works fine, for the second time it shows this error:

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
>   Action failed:
>
> ```
> c:ChildComponent$controller$jsLoaded [Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined]
> Callback failed: apex://Call/ACTION$getServiceXMl
> Failing descriptor: {c:ChildComponent$controller$jsLoaded}
> ```

Its says so about the line `map.addLayer(angleMarker);`

```
<aura:component access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="cID" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="cGeoData" type="Object"/>
    <ltng:require styles="/resource/leaflet/leaflet.css" />
    <ltng:require scripts="/resource/leaflet/leaflet.js,/resource/marker/marker-direction.js,/resource/providers"/>

<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.cGeoData}" action="{!c.jsLoaded}"/>
<div class="map" id="map"></div>
```

```
({
    jsLoaded: function(component, event, helper) {
    if(map==null){
        map=new L.map('map').setView([component.get("v.cGeoData").longitude, component.get("v.cGeoData").latitude], 13);
            L.tileLayer.provider('HERE.terrainDay', {
                app_id: 'removed for stack exchange',
                app_code: 'removed for stack exchange'
            }).addTo(map);
    }else if(map != null){
        map.invalidateSize();
        map.remove();
        L.map('map').setView([component.get("v.cGeoData").longitude, component.get("v.cGeoData").latitude], 13);
    }
    var list =
        [
            {"lon":component.get("v.cGeoData").latitude,"keyFlag":"0","id":1,"lat":component.get("v.cGeoData").longitude}
        ];
    var offSiteX = 0;
    var offSiteY = 0;

    for(var i in list){
        if(i % 3 != 0){
            continue
        }
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = '/resource/marker25';
        var lat = Number(list[i].lat) + offSiteY;
        var lon = Number(list[i].lon) - offSiteX;
        var latlng = {lat: lat, lon: lon};
        var labelFlag = false;
        var misc = {
            label: list[i].id,
            labelFlag: labelFlag,
            labelColor: 'black',
            img: img
        };
        // use angeMaker plugin
        var angleMarker = L.angleMarker(latlng, misc);
        var angle = component.get("v.cGeoData").direction;
        if(i > '0'){
            var previousLatLng = {lat: list[i-1].lat, lon:  list[i-1].lon};
            var nextLanLng = {lat: list[i].lat, lon:  list[i].lon};
            // get angele between A(previousPoint) and B(nextPoint)
            angle = angleMarker.getAngle(previousLatLng, nextLanLng);
        }
        // set angele A -> B
        angleMarker.setHeading(angle);
        map.addLayer(angleMarker);
    }}})
```

This error occurred after I put in the if statement in the js controller (`if(map==null)`), It showed the "map already initialized" error before.

What can I do to solve this? Maybe the structure of the code isn't sufficient?